# Nginx downloads index php instead of serving it in Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, nginx

As the title says nginx downloads index php.
I have a wordpress site and I have issued ssl cerificate for my domain.

Just to mention if I go to `https://example.com/index.php` then it goes to the homepage and works as it should, but If I go to `https://example.com` the it downloads index.php file.

below is my server context:

```
server {
listen 443;

ssl on;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;

ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/priv.key;



ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";

server_name example.com www.example.com;

root /var/www/mywebsite/;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

 location / {
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
limit_req zone=myzone burst=200;
  }

rewrite wp-content/uploads(/_pda/.*\.\w+)$ "/index.php?pda_v3_pf=$1" last;
rewrite private/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ "/index.php?pda_v3_pf=$1&pdav3_rexypo=ymerexy" last;

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

location = /50x.html {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  } 

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
 }

location ~* (\.css|\.pdf)$ {
valid_referers blocked irir.lv;
if ($invalid_referer) {
return 444;
  }
}

location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
expires 365d;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Test your configuration using `nginx -t` and see what files Nginx is using with `nginx -T`

Comment: @Richard Smith it gives success message that nginx.conf test is succesfful

Comment: There must be index.html or any html file in root

Comment: The issue was that Cloudflare had cached the php file and kept making downloading. Purge the cache on Cloudflare.

Comment: @Vasim Shaikh. This domain is not going over Cloudflare.
and there is html file in the root

Comment: Just remove that file after taking backup

Comment: @VasimShaikih Can you be more precise? What file do I have to remove?

Comment: Case two. I think you need to check configuration with reference link  :
https://serverfault.com/questions/322018/nginx-not-executing-php-files

Comment: @VasimShaikih This really doesn`t help since info in your given link doesnt explain the subject. Its tells to move root directive to the server context whitch I have done before I made this post